# Problems with audio

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

Ok, so I've spent quite some time to try and make my ubuntu 18.04 laptop (yoga 920, dualboot) show anything but "Dummy output" in sound options with no luck. My investigation so far:

The sound works fine in windows, so a hardware problem is ruled out.
I've updated the kernel a few hours ago,  `uname -a` outputs
`4.15.0-60-generic`. I've also tried pruging everything related to `libasound2`, `alsa` and `pulseaudio`.
Now, `lspci -v`
outputs the following, among some other stuff:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
    Memory at 2ffb018000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 2ffb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

`lsmod` also lists the modules, so definitely no problems with hardware, nor with kernel modules. `pacmd list-sources` lists only a dummy output device, which is (probably) expected, as `aplay -l` spews out `aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...`. I do have the `audio` permission group, so running with `sudo` does nothing. `cat /proc/asound/cards` also says `no soundcards`.

So basically I think alsa cannot communicate properly with the kernel modules or something, or cannot configure itself for the soundcard properly.

What I have tried so far:
Reinstalling the kernel and everything sound related -- no luck. Adding `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` or `generic` -- no luck. Banging my head against the wall -- no luck either.

Any help on how to investigate this would be appreciated, most of the stuff I could find on google is either outdated or does not help.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)? There are 4 examples of where this issue occurs. Read the 3rd example first.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried it yet, use command `sudo lspci` in terminal. This is to detect your sound card and I assume to also install drivers.

The link for this is: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en

Answer (score 0):

A combination of reinstallations of all of the components and cranking the sound up suddenly fixed the issue, and I have no bloody idea how. Alsa mixer used to fail to start yesterday, saying "no soundcards found" or something, yet today it worked perfectly fine and everything pretty much works. I am lost, confused and scared. Never again will I mess with sound on linux.